# Find out how many documents have the "property_type" "House", and include "Changing table" as one of the "amenities"?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

> I have tried this method but it keeps saying 0

db.listingsAndReviews.find({ "property_type": {"$eq": "$House" } },
{ "amenities" : { "$eq": "$Changing table" }}).count()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.listingsAndReviews.find({$and:[{ "property_type":"House" }, { "amenities" : "Changing table" }]}).count()
```

Comment: Please describe what you which changes you made to the original code and why they are necessary.

Comment: there are another way in original questio `House` as value don't should `$` in value